# edit .htaccess to load php extension?

Tags: php

I follow this post to enable PHP5 XSL extension on apache server:
[.htaccess instead of php.ini](http://drupal.org/node/255970)

```
php_extension xsl.so
```

After added the line above, it show the 500 internal server error. and recommend?

Comment: tail -f /var/apache2/error_log

Comment: can you check if you enabled this kind of settings in .htaccesss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache accepts PHP settings inside `.htaccess` files only if PHP is installed as a module and thus loaded as part of it. If PHP is set up as CGI you're out of luck - this won't work.

If you can't directly edit the `php.ini` try putting a php.ini in the same folder as the `.htaccess` (sometimes it just works - if there's `suphp` or `phpsuexec` installed).

Another thing you can try is [dl()](http://www.php.net/dl).

Answer (score 0):

I think `php_extension xsl.so` is not correct, allowed config for php apache modul is only `php_value`, `php_flag`, `php_admin_value` and `php_admin_flag`:

@see: https://www.php.net/manual/configuration.changes.php

I found the same post about loading php modules by htaccess, and I tried to load it with:

```
php_value php_extension curl
```

#### Tested in `Apache/2.4.41 (Win64)` and `PHP/7.3.13`

This makes no error 500, but it seems to have no effect on my loaded php modules (to allow overwriting apache config via .htaccess I enabled `AllowOverride All`).

And even if this works you should add `<IfModule>` blocks around this line like in this comment https://serverfault.com/a/1013773/200655

An alternative could be the php function [dl()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.dl.php) unfortunately it is removed in php apache module in many php versions.