# how to enable php mb_string only for 1 host?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mbstring

I have a centOS machine with cPanel. We have compiled PHP with mb_string and it works fine. We want to disable it in all hosting accounts except one, So we have disabled it in php.ini , but want to enable it in the specific host.

I know this is possible with apache's .htaccess file. But how, and what commands? Any insights?

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [edit .htaccess to load php extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271910/edit-htaccess-to-load-php-extension)

Comment: That one refers to http://drupal.org/node/255970 again btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can manipulate the extension/module itself via htaccess. Sure, you can adjust values, but the extension needs to be loaded for the values to have any effect.

Perhaps you can do with a per-user php.ini set-up?

http://www.sant-media.co.uk/2010/02/whmcpanel-per-user-php-ini-under-apache-2-x-and-suphp/

http://bibekshrestha.com.np/blogs/post/2010/02/05/using-custom-phpini-cpanel-server

Comment: Thank you very much dakdad. the second link helps  a lot !