# how to add .dll extensions to .htaccesss file

Tags: php

I am currently on shared hosting.I need to know how to add extensions that I need via htaccess.Normally, I would update the php.ini file with the following:

extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll

I put below lines in the htaccess file to make this occur.

php_extension mbstring.so
php_extension php_exif.so

But I am geeting internal server error.

Please help.

Comment: @ Michel I am Getting 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: The Apache error_log file will tell you in detail what the error is. Always look there first.

Comment: @Michael I found exif_read_data() [function.exif-read-data]: Unable to open file in error_log file

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to include last two lines in the .htaccess file since you have added the extensions in php.ini.

Comment: yes but it did't worked for me so i have added it in .htaccess file

Comment: I don't have access of php.ini file.i want to add mbstring,php_exif extensions via .htaccess file.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I have had that problem before, check out this post for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271910/edit-htaccess-to-load-php-extension