# intl php extension exception zend framework 2 shared hosting

Tags: php, zend-framework2, shared, intl

I finally managed to deploy my ZF2 site to a shared (and also free) hosting.

Everything seems to be working the right way, except a section that has a form.
This is the error I'm getting:

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend\Form\Exception\ExtensionNotLoadedException'
with message 'Zend\Form\View\Helper component requires the intl PHP extension' in
/.../vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormMonthSelect.php
```

In the form, there's a field where the user is supposed to select his/her birthday. I think that the problem is there.

How I'm i supposed to enable that extension in the server? Or at least, modify something in my zf2 application so it doesn't need that extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagnosis is correct -- `FormMonthSelect` [does require](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormMonthSelect.php#L56) `intl` extension.

Managing php extensions is usually something done by sys admins, so you'd either ask the hosting company to enable it or try to squeeze that in through htaccess (iffy, [edit .htaccess to load php extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271910/edit-htaccess-to-load-php-extension)). Other then that I can only advise not to use anything that relies on `intl`, so maybe a simple text field with date parsing done by you manually.