# How can i enable php extension with .htaccess file

Tags: php, php-extension, intl

I need to enable `php_intl` extension only in a subdomain of my website, so i use the `.htaccess` file to do it with this code.

```
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
    php_extension_dir php_intl.dll
    php_extension php_intl.dll
</IfModule>
```

But not work.
Someone helpe me, please?

Answer (score 0):

The directive `php_extension_dir` should be:

```
php_extension_dir <path_to__php_extensions>
```

Where `<path_to_php_extensions>` is the absolute path to where your PHP extensions are installed. Simply putting the file name here does nothing, since a path value is expected.

If this still does not work, then PHP is set up as CGI and therefore cannot use htaccess to load modules. [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271910/edit-htaccess-to-load-php-extension) if that is the case.