# Is it possible to configure Mysqlnd Api Extension from htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mysqli, mysqlnd

I am using **Hostinger** free hosting and they don't provide PHP settings page to configure the `php.ini` .

Recently I came up with an error

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()
```

I did a little bit of research on why this error and it turns out that may be `mysqli` is diabled but thats not the case for me. I'm using PHP 7.

Also I have checked the `mysqlnd` is enabled in my `phpinfo` page. But the `Api Extension` is set to `no value` which seems to be causing the problem.

I want to implement this **configuration**

```
./configure --with-mysql=mysqlnd 
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd 
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
```

So called up the Hostinger customer service and it turns out they are not really understanding my point.

I want to use both mysqli, pdo & mysql.
May I please know if there is any way to change the **MySQLnd API EXTENSION** using **.htaccess**.

TIA

Comment: Generally on shared hosting, the answer is no. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487387/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-with-htaccess-file) for info.

Comment: Please re-check the url. I don't believe the same is relevant. If it is please describe.

Comment: That link describes how to enable an extension, including mysqlnd, from htaccess, so long as the server has mod_php.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

It can be installed only one of two ways

1. You compiled it yourself with `mysqlnd` support
2. You installed the package or DLL

Both are server level configurations

Comment: Does it mean I have to completely rely on the service provider? Is there anything can be done from our end to solve the issue? Would be happy to know more on this

Comment: It does if you don't admin the server